# rounded corners with CSS creates a line

Tags: css

I need to display some content within an area that will have rounded corners. The images associated with these corners are in a single .png file. In an effort to show the rounded corners, I'm using the following:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:800px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:12px; width:12px;background-image:url(/images.png);background-position:108px 48px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="background-color:silver;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height:12px; width:12px;background-image:url(/images.png);background-position:124px 48px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:silver;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>My content goes here.</td>
    <td style="background-color:silver;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Oddly, there is a thin line between my upper corners and the content. This line does not appear between the middle columns though. At first I thought I was sizing my images wrong, but they look fine. Does anybody have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: please for the love of the almighty CSS gods don't use tables for layouts!

Comment: and learn to accept answers otherwise no one will be motivated to help you

Comment: :) you're right. I need to go through and accept people's answers. my bad.

Comment: You are in no way creating "rounded corners with CSS", that would be using CSS3 `border-radius`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anybody have any ideas of what
>   I'm doing wrong?

- Using tables for layout.
- Using an image-based technique for rounded corners.
- Using inline styles *(unless you're using them purely for brevity in asking the question)*.

> how I can fix this?

- Use this HTML:

  ```
  <div id="content"></div>
  ```
- Use this CSS:

  ```
  width: 800px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  ```

We're using the CSS3 property [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/border-radius), which will work in IE9 and other modern browsers.

If you require rounded corners in older versions of Internet Explorer, you should use [**CSS3PIE**](http://css3pie.com/).

It's as simple as downloading a file, and adding a single line to your CSS:

```
#myElement {
    ...
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/2JSae/) *(without CSS3PIE)*

Comment: So, mainly everything then! :)